# How to understand the map for the statistical mechanics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Recently I found [a very interesting map](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-044-statistical-physics-i-spring-2013/readings-notes-slides/MIT8_044S13_L1.pdf) which seems to contain all these elements one will meet in the statistical mechanics.

So does anybody want to share their understanding of this map?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From reading the PDF, issued by MIT OpenCourseWare, (that map is the first page of the PDF), it seems a straightforward outline of the key points of  an SM - TD course, stressing the importance of probability, (the language reference) and then showing how it will be structured.

I can't see any more significance than that in it..